# Android Studio keeps showing Missing Permission, even though i am handling it explicitly. How do I fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

While using Google Map API every time I add relate to location like here below, Android Studio keep showing error :

```
private fun enableMyLocationOnMap() {
        googleMap.setPadding(0, ViewUtils.dpToPx(48f), 0, 0)
        googleMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true //<----ERROR
}
```

Error: Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

I am handling permission explicitly:

```
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        when {
            PermissionUtils.isAccessFineLocationGranted(this) -> {
                when {
                    PermissionUtils.isLocationEnable(this) -> {
                        setUpLocationListener()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        PermissionUtils.showGPSNotEnableDialog(this)
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> {
                PermissionUtils.requestAccessFineLocation(
                    this
                    , LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    when {
                        PermissionUtils.isLocationEnable(this) -> {
                            setUpLocationListener()
                        }
                        else -> {
                            PermissionUtils.showGPSNotEnableDialog(this)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where PermissionUtils.kt :

```
object PermissionUtils {
    fun requestAccessFineLocation(activity: AppCompatActivity, requestId: Int) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            requestId
        )

    }

    fun isAccessFineLocationGranted(context: Context): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    fun isLocationEnable(context: Context): Boolean {
        val locationManager: LocationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    }

    fun showGPSNotEnableDialog(context: Context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.enable_gps))
            .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.required_for_this_app))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.enable_now)) { _, _ ->
                context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
            }
            .show()
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml have :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Not sure but try this: https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-turn-on-gps-programmatically-d585cf29c1ef

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio cannot "see" that you made the check elsewhere in the code. Also, it is theoretically possible for the user to revoke the permission between when you're checking for it and its usage.

You need to do the check directly before using the permission. For example:

```
private fun enableMyLocationOnMap() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        googleMap.setPadding(0, ViewUtils.dpToPx(48f), 0, 0)
        googleMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true //<----ERROR
    } else {
        // request permission flow
    }
}
```